# File is being used by another Thread

Tags: c#, file

I am reading data from serial port and writing it on text field using Timer event , but when writing those data to file in timer event method or `SerialDataReceived` method. I get file is being used by another thread.
Even I set **FileShare.Write** , but still having the same problem.

Comment: We need to see your code.

Comment: and additional to the source code add the error message

Comment: Make sure u should dispose the file resource once used, using(){ }  will help, but for more information put the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your problem description, I think you are trying to write the file from two places Timer event and SerialDataReceived event. So there is a chance of both trying to access the file at the same time. Better and a synchronizing block using lock. It could be better to understand the problem if the source code can be shared.

Comment: Thanks , I was accessing file from tow places .

Answer (score 1):

I changed the algorithm ,usage a Array List for storing the data coming from the 
SerialDataRecievedEvent then usage timer event to write into the file ! 
It worked !